# Properly handling menu items in a custom module

Tags: 7, routes

In my module I need to install custom menu items (add to existing `main-menu`) on the front-end side. So basically it's a simple one-time operation, yet it rises some questions about the proper way to deal with programatic menu items in general.

1. `hook_install` + `menu_link_save` sounds good for installing the items, `hook_uninstall` + `menu_link_delete` - for uninstalling, but how am I supposed to find out the `$mlid` parameter of the menu link - required by the `menu_link_delete` function?
2. Would `hook_enable` and `hook_disable` be more suitable?
3. How do I protect my module's menu items from deleting on the admin UI side?

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically add/remove menu items on install/uninstall and/or enable/disable events. But that's *not* how we do usually.

Implement [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and you will be fine to go with almost any menu item implementation.

A few points. 
Set menu router item's `'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` and it will now be in a menu. Unless you set `'menu_name'`, it will be placed in the "navigation" menu. 
See the huge (and very helpful) text on the page. Also, have a look at [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) for high-quality hook_menu examples.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ayesh. Let's see if I'm lucky today. On my bilingual site I try to programatically assign a menu router to a particular language, by adding `'options' => array('language' => 'fr')` To no avail. Should this work?